# invalid bytes in UTF8

Tags: json, character-encoding, couchdb

During usage of CouchDB and json I've got error

```
Invalid JSON: {{error,{11219, "lexical error: invalid bytes in UTF8 string.\n"}},

request looks more less like this:
builder.request(Method.POST, "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

Comment: Removed tags in title

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that you are sending valid JSON in the request body.

Your POST **header** should be `content-type: application/json` and your POST **body** should be a document, for example `{"greeting":"Hello, world!"}`.